# Como detectar que a div foi rolada até o final?

Tags: jquery, html

Preciso saber se a uma determinada `div` foi rolada até o final, utilizando jQuery. Estou tendo problemas pois a altura da `div` não é constante. O objetivo é que a rolagem automática da `div` não ocorra, a menos que ela já esteja rolada pelo usuário até o fim.

Código da rolagem automática:

```js
$(".roller").animate({"scrollTop": $(".roller")[0].scrollHeight}, 500);
```

Comment: Se você está tendo problemas, então já tentou algo. Pode nos mostrar como você fez? Talvez esteja próximo da solução final. E qual foi o problema com ela?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal simplesmente não funcionou travava a execução do script. Apaguei o código antigo já faz um mês, mas tive que voltar ao projeto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como não existe uma propriedade "scroll bottom", o jeito é fazer uns cálculos usando a propriedade `scrollTop` do seu elemento (o quanto ele já rolou a partir do início), sua propriedade `scrollHeight` (o máximo que ele pode rolar) e a propriedade `clientHeight` do documento (o tamanho do *viewport*):

```js
var top = $(".roller")[0].scrollTop;
var maxTop = $(".roller")[0].scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

Se ambos forem iguais, a rolagem está no seu valor máximo. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/PqPD2/2/)

Se necessário, substitua `document.documentElement.clientHeight` pela altura do contêiner do seu `.roller`, caso ela seja diferente da altura do *viewport*.

Comment: Somei também 100px de "carência", para que a rolagem automática ocorra mesmo quando ela não estiver totalmente rolada, mas precise ir para lá, pois há uma nova informação a ser exibida.